# accessing in the sub-folder of a folder in python

Tags: python-3.x, subdirectory

What I am trying to do is to access the images saved in my path that is E:/project/plane
but unable to get access.
I tried using glob.glob, all I'm getting is access to the subfolder not to the images inside the subfolder.
I also tried to take the name of the subfolder as an input combine it with the path but still can't get access to the folder.
Can anyone help me with how can I achieve this task?

here is my Python code:

```
import os
import glob
import cv2

path= "E:\project\%s"% input("filename")
print(path)

for folder in glob.glob(path  + '*' , recursive=True):
    print(folder)
```

Comment: First of all, `\ ` is an escape character in a python string, use either `/` or `\\ ` to avoid potential errors.

Are you using the extension of the images, i.e. `.png` or `.bmp`?

Comment: Okay, I'll make it correct and yes its .jpg.